Reading iceberg table in Dremio fails due to "is not Parquet file" and "expected magic number"
I've got a Spark Structured Streaming job that reads data from Kafka and writes them to S3 (NetApp StorageGRID appliance, on-prem) as an Apache Iceberg table (via Nessie catalog).
Afterwards I access the table via Dremio which worked in the beginning, but now it seems that some Parquet files are corrupt - or at least Dremio is not able to read them.
I am getting the following error in Dremio:

IOException: /s3bucket/measurements_7b67d322-277d-4e26-bb8a-c2c833423ca6/data/timestamp_day=2024-06-28/00120-6-b193ded0-6b70-4506-bf77-be6da1863b21-00001.parquet is not a Parquet file. expected magic number [80, 65, 82, 49] at tail, but found [118, -33, 125, -73]

Querying the data via Spark and Starburst/Trino is possible. Downloading the mentioned parquet file and using parquet-tools to show the content works as well.
In the past I used Spark to fully rewrite the table once and then Dremio was able to query the data again, but after some time I got the mentioned error again. So it seems that Spark writes the Iceberg table in a way that lead to such errors.
I could imagine that the streaming job might crash during writes as I have a very low-performant and unstable demo environment here, but as Iceberg uses ACID transactions I would rather expect a rollback than that the invalid files are available for consumers.
Has someone an idea how to fix this issue or even better: What might be the root cause?

The expected sequence  [80, 65, 82, 49] is "PAR1", which all parquet parsers read to say "this is  parquet v1 file", pr E
The actual output is "v!}I", which means that either there is something wrong with the download or the file isn't parquet.
For extra confusion, note that when writing to s3 the write is atomic, so there are never any half-written files.
The parquet format is documented: Parquet File Format. have a look at the file in more detail, especially to see what the header says.

Thanks stevel! I verified the parquet file and it seems to match the format and also has PAR1 at the end. Thus currently I've got three ideas: 1. Dremio downloads only parts of the file (but it's always the same, thus probably not related to network issues) or 2. Dremio has too low resources to read the whole file or 3. Dremio cached the file somewhere and the cache is corrupt
